# one dataGrid with 3 search option

Tags: asp.net

My scenario is : I have one dataGrid with 5-6 columns. i have 3 filters which use 3 SQL queries methods in codeBehind :SearchByName(), SearchByValue() , SearchByDate().I have fourth method show DefaultShow() which display all data without any filters.
Basicly I want when Page is loaded DefaultShow() method to load and then user can choose option for search with RadioButtonList

DefaultShow() code is :

```
 public void DefaultShow()
        {
            string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
            string query = "select Id ,name,value,Description,DateCreate from AllCostView where  IdUser = '" + cui.getCurrentId() + "'";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

                SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                using (DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                    GridViewCost.DataSource = myDataTable;
                    GridViewCost.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                DefaultShow();

        }
```

**But this not work what am I miss?**

My gridViewCode is this :

```
<div class ="gridView">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCost" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CaptionAlign="Top" 
        ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Font-Overline="False" 
        Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" 
         AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="5"
        CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewCost_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Номер" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Име">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Стойност" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Описание" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreate" HeaderText="Дата"   />

        </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle />
        <HeaderStyle  HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
        <PagerStyle />
        <RowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

If it's needed i will post more code . Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Does the query return data if you run it in SQL Server Management Studio?